# Twilio get latest chat channels using Rest API - PHP Laravel

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm trying to get latest chat channels for example Chat Channels with dateCreated or dateUpdated > '2019-11-13 00:00:00'. I couldn't find any resource which uses date attribute to filter results.

Currently we use the Api Endpoint: https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/[ServiceSid]/Channels which is listed in Twilio Api Explorer: https://www.twilio.com/console/api-explorer/chat/chat-channels.

This endpoint returns all chat channels and then stream over it. I'm looking to fit a date filter inside this endpoint or if this is not possible can I have order for chat channels in descending order which would still work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid the [channels list endpoint](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/channel-resource#read-multiple-channel-resources) is neither filterable by `dateCreated` or `dataUpdated` nor can be sorted. The only parameter you can send to list channels is `type` which allows you to filter channels based on whether they are public or private (default is public).